# Python code to find minimum column value with a 15000 line data set

Tags: python, csv

i have a .csv data set (like 15000 items) and i want to find the minimum value.

As i've been searching for an answer, I've found a lot of answers, but people always have the data set they want to find the minimum value of in brackets

```
ex. [0.0, 1.3, 37.7]
```

and then ask Python to find the minimum value. With such a large data set, i cant possibly individually place the data into brackets, how can i call out *a specific column* in my .csv file and then find the minimum value?

(please explain what you are doing, too, i am very new to working with python)

Comment: The brackets are used in python *source* code, whereas you are referencing a *data* file. Turning a data file into source code, as your reference to “individually adding brackets” suggests, is almost always a bad idea. Instead use source code which reads the data file, as answers below suggest.

Comment: 15000 is NOT large at all for modern computers....you can simply read the file using `numpy.genfromtxt(file, usecols=(i,)) where `i` is the column id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- 15,000 items is not 'large'; I have dealt with some 12 million line .csv files in memory (although I had to use 64-bit Python to get enough space!)
- `min()` will work against a generator - that is, one item at a time, instead of all at once

.

```
import csv

with open('myfile.csv', 'rb') as inf:
    incsv = csv.reader(inf)
    column = 1                # the second column (Python counts from 0, per @MRAB's comment)
    datatype = float          # or int, as appropriate (per MvG)
    data = (datatype(row[column]) for row in incsv)    # NB: a generator expression, not a list
    least_value = min(data)
```

Comment: @C0deH4cker: it *quite exactly* answers the question.

Comment: @Hugh Bothwell: You might want to mention that Python counts from 0, so column 1 is the second column.

Comment: Perhaps you should convert the value to a number.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @HughBothwell that the size of the data won't be a problem. However, if for some reason OP prefers to deal with the data row-by-row (ie line-by-line) this provides an alternative.

```
import csv, sys

with open('data.txt', 'rb') as inf:
    min_val = sys.maxint
    col = 0 # column we are searching (this is the 1st column, zero-based index)
    for line in csv.reader(inf):
        val = int(line[col])  # or float() as needed
        if val < min_val:
            min_val = val

    print min_val
```

OP: Happy to clarify any part of the code if unclear.